# Move text on the same line in css

Tags: html, css, styles, html-lists

My issue is that in the footer if the second div has less text.. the 3rd div is a lot higher than the 4th div when the screen is smaller. I want to put a fixed height on the first div.

I have tried:

```
.footer ul {
  height: 100px;
}
```

but it overlaps the text

[image]

```
<div class="footer">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
        <ul>
          <li class="Heading">TEST</li>
          <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
        <ul>
          <li class="Heading">TEST</li>
          <li><a href="#">Test Account</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
        <ul class="padding-none">
          <li class="Heading">SUBSCRIBE TO NEWSLETTER</li>
          <input type="text" id="sub-input" name="subscribe" placeholder="Enter your email address" />
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
        <ul>
          <li class="Heading">Test</li>
          <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/d81v1k01/)**

Comment: Do you mind posting a working example of your code?

Comment: Well i am confused, do you want to give a fixed height to your first column or you just want to make all the column same height??

Comment: Demo https://jsfiddle.net/d81v1k01/ @scarsam

Comment: all the columns same height @M.KHossain

Comment: @user4756836 any progress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly sure if this is what you're looking for but try adding this to your code. `clear` to the HTML and the CSS I posted below. Here is the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/scarsam/d81v1k01/1/).

### HTML (Add this to the third div in the footer)

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 clear">
  <ul class="padding-none">
    <li class="Heading">SUBSCRIBE TO NEWSLETTER</li>
    <input type="text" id="sub-input" name="subscribe" placeholder="Enter your email address" />
  </ul>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.clear {
  clear: both;
}
@media only screen and (min-width : 768px)  {
  .clear {
    clear: none;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using .row-eq-height class in row and column to know more please visit

[Bootstrap equal-height columns](http://getbootstrap.com.vn/examples/equal-height-columns/)

Here is a example :

```
<div class="row row-eq-height">
    <div class="col-xs-3"><ul>
      <li class="Heading">Test</li>
      <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
    </ul></div>
    <div class="col-xs-3"><ul>
      <li class="Heading">TEST</li>
      <li><a href="#">Test Account</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
    </ul></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4"><ul class="padding-none">
      <li class="Heading">SUBSCRIBE TO NEWSLETTER</li>
      <input type="text" id="sub-input" name="subscribe" placeholder="Enter your email address" />
    </ul></div>
  <div class="col-xs-4"><ul>
      <li class="Heading">Test</li>
      <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
    </ul></div>
  </div>
```

Hope that help.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the `row-eq-height` ( as stated in an answer before ) but if by just putting that class, it's still not working, use this css code for the row

```
.row-eq-height {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}
```

see snippet below or [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d81v1k01/2/)

```css
footer{
 background-color: #333742;
 color: #8b94a4;
 padding-top: 50px;
 float: bottom;
}
.row-eq-height {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display:         flex;
}
#sub-input{
 background-color: #393e4a;
 color : #7e8796;
 border: 0;
 border-radius: 20px;
 width: 250px;
 height: 40px;
 padding : 14px;
 padding-left: 30px;
}

.footer ul{
 list-style: none;
}

.footer ul a{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #8b94a4;
}

.footer ul li{
 padding: 7px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="footer">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row row-eq-height">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
        <ul>
          <li class="Heading">TEST</li>
          <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
        <ul>
          <li class="Heading">TEST</li>
          <li><a href="#">Test Account</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
        <ul class="padding-none">
          <li class="Heading">SUBSCRIBE TO NEWSLETTER</li>
          <input type="text" id="sub-input" name="subscribe" placeholder="Enter your email address" />
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
        <ul>
          <li class="Heading">Test</li>
          <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```